# Paypal Pro DoDirectPayment API as a third party With No US/UK/Canada Credentials

Tags: paypal

I'm looking to integrate paypal as a payment gateways for my customers.

I provide a software online to customer who sells products to users, so I'm developping paypal as a third party, so the money is directly transferred in my customer's paypal account, and not mine.

I have create my account in paypal so I have my credentials, and let my customer grant permission to my app manually as write here (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/admin/third-party/ )

I'm using the merchantSDK and DoDirectPayment method which is only available in US, UK & Canada.

My question is about the location of my acccount. Do I also need an account in US/UK/Canada (DoDirectPayment Api can just be use in US/UK/Canada - as write here : http://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/paypal/forums/soap/dodirectpayment-merchant-country-not-supported), or the only requirement is that my customer must have a US/UK/Canada business paypal account ?

Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the account actually running the DoDirectPayment call would need Pro enabled.

Comment: If I understand, my account will run the DoDirectPayment (because it's my API credentials), and my account is not a pro account and is not located in US/UK/Canada, so it will not work ? Even if the customer account who granted permission to me is a pro account and located in US/UK/Canada

Comment: Well, you're running it on their behalf, though, so it's their account that needs Pro enabled.

Comment: Just like if I were to setup a hosted online store solution.  I may not even have Pro enabled because I take PayPal and I'm fine with that.  Users of my platform, though, may have Pro, so my solution can make those calls for them just fine because they do have Pro enabled on their account.